# move_base action topics exist but client stuck on waitForServer

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `rostopic list`, I see the following (among others)

```
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/goal
/move_base/result
/move_base/status
/move_base_simple/goal
```

However, my action client is still permanently stuck waiting for `/move_base`

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;

MoveBaseClient move_base_client("/move_base", true);
while(!move_base_client.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0)))
{
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
}
```

Everything is running on the same PC.

What am I doing wrong??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345012/move_base-action-topics-exist-but-client-stuck-on-waitforserver/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2020-02-25**:
Are you providing odom topic? If I remember correctly it waits for odom to appear.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-02-26**:
can you please update your question with the full output of `rostopic list`. Also what is the name of the node where you are creating the action client?

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-02-27**:
@pavel92 thx for the response, but I believe I've found the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out `move_base` is not "fully" up until a map is published.  It's strange how the topics show up but the action server only becomes available after the map is published.

Notice that move_base action server is the [first thing created](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/603ec3440105357a4efa672f48585a182f7c84c0/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L60) when move_base constructor is called, but is only started [near the end](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/603ec3440105357a4efa672f48585a182f7c84c0/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L169).

My problem is that somewhere along the way in move_base's constructor, the plugin `static_layer` is loaded which [spins until a map is received](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/f2d12a9d94a2723452a70275f5a013cdab5441d5/costmap_2d/plugins/static_layer.cpp#L95).

Somehow I wasn't smart enough to correlate the message

> Requesting the map...

With `move_base` not being fully constructed, hence hanging on `waitForServer`

I also wouldn't be surprised if there are other things that need to happen before move_base can be fully constructed and the action server started. e.g. as Choco93 suggests, odom needs to be published (I have not verified this)

I may not be seeing the full picture, but I would have placed the creation of the action server "nearer" to the starting of the server.  I believe this would improve debuggability in a sense that I won't be seeing the topics while the server is in fact inoperable.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-02-26**:
Actually, `odom` is not needed for the action server to show up correctly. You can check that if dig through the documentation of [waitForServer](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#a53557d70d66e77067cd2c0a782fa9451) call and the other methods that are called within ([waitForActionServerToStart](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib/html/connection__monitor_8cpp_source.html#l00219) and [isServerConnected](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib/html/connection__monitor_8cpp_source.html#l00179) ) . The only check that is done afaik is waiting for topics based on defined timeout.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-02-26**:
So I still think that it is a namespace issue. You client is trying to connect to a server that does not exist

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-02-26**:
Hmm that's strange, as I did not fix it by changing any topic names, but by publishing to `/map`