# move_base state for FlexBE

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, automation

I'm trying to build robot high-level control using [FlexBE](http://philserver.bplaced.net/fbe/) behavior engine

The task is to make robot to move through the list of waypoints. The project is on ROS 1, I'm using **move_base** package for navigation and **move_base_state** from [repository](https://github.com/FlexBE/generic_flexbe_states/blob/master/flexbe_navigation_states/src/flexbe_navigation_states/move_base_state.py)

When starting my behavior getting the following output:

```
[WARN] [1703094334.163039]: Waiting for action client /move_base...
[ERROR] [1703094334.664775]: Action client /move_base timed out!
[WARN] [1703094334.667201]: Unable to send navigation action goal:
Cannot send goal for action client /move_base: Topic not available.
[INFO] [1703094334.670376]: State result: mb > failed
[INFO] [1703094334.688127]: State update: mb > failed
```

The thing is that move_base is already running and all the topics are available. rostopic list output:

```
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/goal
/move_base/home
/move_base/recovery_status
/move_base/result
/move_base/status
/move_base_node/current_goal
/move_base_simple/goal
/odom
```

How could I deal with this problem? I've already discovered a possible [issue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/move-base-action-topics-exist-but-client-stuck-on-waitforserver), but I still don't understand what the matter in my case